# Need to identify higher value and lower value stored in the multivalue field

Tags: entities

I have a Multivalued field called temperature in that everyday temperature values are stored. In that i would like to identify the highest and lowest value from that field.I found computed field module will do that but i would like to know how i achieve same in computed field.please anyone guide me do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never put code in the database. It is impossible to maintain and debug, and you spend hours wasting your time.

The computed field gives you the option to [add the code to a custom module](https://www.drupal.org/node/126522).

My answer used these three fields added to the content type:

- Temp (machine name field_temp, integer, multi-value)
- Highest (machine name field_highest, computed, int)
- Lowest (machine name field_lowest, computed, int)

**Method:**
[Create a custom module](https://www.drupal.org/node/1074360) (just module and info files), then add this to the module file:

```
function computed_field_field_highest_compute(&$entity_field, $entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items) {
  $temps = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_temp');
  if (count($temps)) {
    $max = $temps[0]['value'];
    foreach($temps as $temp) {
      $max = $temp['value'] > $max ? $temp['value'] : $max;
    }
    $entity_field[0]['value'] = $max;
  }
}

function computed_field_field_lowest_compute(&$entity_field, $entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items) {
  $temps = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_temp');
  if (count($temps)) {
    $min = $temps[0]['value'];
    foreach($temps as $temp) {
      $min = $temp['value'] < $min ? $temp['value'] : $min;
    }
    $entity_field[0]['value'] = $min;
  }
}
```

Read the [documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/node/126522) for the computed field module to see the naming convention for adding a custom function. The function name is also visible in the field settings.

In the two functions I refer to 'field_temp'. It is the machine name of the multi-value field holding the temperature values.